# How do I bypass a fatal error handling in CakePHP custom Authenticator Object?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, fatal-error, custom-authentication

I'm doing a soap based authentication in my custom Authenticator object. Sometime the soap endpoint may not be available. This in sequence will throw a

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
```

and then will be handled by

```
ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'SOAP-ERROR: Par...', '/home/bombadil/...', 100)
```

in lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php
and then the page will be redirected to lib Cake/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp

Now, how do I redirect to my login page again and showing a toned down error message instead of throwing the unfriendly page of fatal_error.ctp? I can't afford to create another fatal_error page because I want to redirect again to my login page.

Thanks

Comment: You can do so by checking the requested action using exception handling in AppController's beforeFilter() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, I raise an exception upon unsuccessful connection in the Soap datasource and catch it at my model which doing the Soap based authentication.